# Which HTTP headers may JavaScript set?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Does the W3C specify which HTTP headers an XMLHttpRequest may set? If so, have they published a document justifying these requirements with security reasons?

Is it up to the browser to restrict HTTP headers at its own discretion? If so, is there a document or collection of documents online that lists the quirks of different XHR implementations or is it necessary to find that information in the documentation for each implementation?

Comment: there's a list of forbidden headers in [the XHR spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

W3C has [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) about headers allowed by `setRequestHeader`

> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of
>   the following headers:
>
> - Accept-Charset
> - Accept-Encoding
> - Access-Control-Request-Headers
> - Access-Control-Request-Method
> - Connection
> - Content-Length
> - Cookie
> - Cookie2
> - Content-Transfer-Encoding
> - Date
> - Expect
> - Host
> - Keep-Alive
> - Origin
> - Referer
> - TE
> - Trailer
> - Transfer-Encoding
> - Upgrade
> - User-Agent
> - Via
>
> … or if the start of header is a case-insensitive match for Proxy- or
>   Sec- (including when header is just Proxy- or Sec-).
>
> The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control
>   those aspects of transport. **This guarantees data integrity to some
>   extent.** Header names starting with Sec- are not allowed to be set to
>   allow new headers to be minted that are guaranteed not to come from
>   XMLHttpRequest.

Also you may consider:

If header is not in the [author-request-headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#author-request-headers) list append header with its associated value to the list and terminate these steps.

About browsers implementation, I've found this nice test: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webapps/diff/5814514eeba4/tests/XMLHttpRequest/setrequestheader-header-forbidden.htm that you cant use to find current differences.

For example, **IE** has this definition of security on headers:

[IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536752.aspx): Refer to [RFC2616, Section 14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html): Header Field Definitions for a general list of standard headers. The server is ultimately responsible for honoring the headers of the request. By far the most common request header is Content-Type, which is required by some XML Web services.